# Why isn't my mysqli_connect connecting? It says no hostname was specified when one is

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm writing a simple blogging web app for my portfolio and I've come across this strange problem. I wrote a PHP script to connect to a database and read and write data to a database by RESTful calls.

I've done this before in other programs with no problems, but in this one I get an error. I wrote a simple test page to check that the RESTful calls would work before I started using them in my main app. Instead of working, I got an error back from my PHP script.

The error goes like this:

> Warning: mysqli_connect() [function.mysqli-connect]: (HY000/2002): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/No-MySQL-hostname-was-specified' (2) in /home/releesquirrel/storage.electricsquirrel.net/SimpleBlog/php/model_SimpleBlog.php on line 35

The code leading up to line 35 goes like this:

```
class model_SimpleBlog {
// Properties

// Database Info
private $serverName = "mysql.electricsquirrel.net";
private $userName = "esqrl_client";
private $userPassword = "fakepassword";
private $dbaseName = "esquirrel_simpleblog";


// Methods
public function model_SimpleBlog() {
    //
}

// Load the ten latest entries after an offset
public function loadEntries($offset) {

    $result = false;

    // Connect to the Database Server

    $connection = mysqli_connect($serverName, $userName, $userPassword, $dbaseName);
```

I've changed the password for privacy but that's the code that's throwing the error. I'm completely stumped. I've used code similar to this with no problems before, and I've tried googling the error code with no luck.

Does anybody know why I'm getting this error and what I can do to fix my code?

Comment: It's a variable scope issue. Your function can't access `$serverName`, because that variable isn't in scope inside your function (ditto for the rest of the variables, too)

Comment: You need to use `$this->variablename` --

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PHP, you need to refer to object variables with `$this->`:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect($this->serverName, $this->userName, $this->userPassword, $this->dbaseName);
```

`$serverName`, for instance, looks for a variable with that name in the scope of the function. Obviously none exists.

See the manual for more information on [PHP object properties](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php).